# Convert IRestResponse to IRestResponse<T>

Tags: restsharp

I have executed `RestRequest` and got non-typed `IRestResponse`.

How can I convert it to `IRestResponse<T>`?

For example `IRestResponse<MyErrorData>` or `IRestResponse<MyData>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the generic overload of `Execute`:

```
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
request.AddParameter("AccountSid", _accountSid, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
```

`Execute<T>` is the key to getting back a typed response.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, depending on the version of *RestSharp* you have installed, `Execute<T>` threw a compiler error. (Tho it seems fine in v106.15.)

Another option is to cast it, which seems to work when the first option doesn't:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();
IRestResponse<T> response = (IRestResponse<T>)client.Execute(request);
```

Also, don't forget that your method (or class) must be decorated with the `T` type parameter:

Eg

```
partial void InterceptResponse<T>(IRestRequest request, ref IRestResponse<T> response)
    ...
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    IRestResponse<T> response = client.Execute<T>(request);
    (or IRestResponse<T> response = (IRestResponse<T>)client.Execute(request);)
    ....
```

(In this example, I'm intercepting a `RestResponse`, doing something, such as re-calling, and passing back the new response as `ref response`.)